Optimal transport and the geometry of singular measures on fractal Sets
Let $K$ be a self-similar fractal set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Hausdorff dimension $d < n$, equipped with a self-similar measure $\mu$ supported on $K$. Let $\mathcal{P}(K)$ denote the space of probability measures on $K$.
Consider the Wasserstein distance $W_p$ on $\mathcal{P}(K)$ defined by
$$W_p(\nu_1, \nu_2) = \left( \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\nu_1, \nu_2)} \int_{K \times K} |x-y|^p d\pi(x,y) \right)^{1/p},$$
where $\Pi(\nu_1, \nu_2)$ is the set of couplings between $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$.
What is the asymptotic behavior of the Wasserstein distance $W_p(\mu, \nu)$ as $\nu$ approaches $\mu$ in the weak-* topology, where $\nu$ is a singular measure with respect to $\mu$.
In particular, does there exist a function $f: (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ such that for any sequence of singular measures $\{\nu_k\}$ converging weak-* to $\mu$, we have
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{W_p(\mu, \nu_k)}{f(|\nu_k - \mu|)} = C, $$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes a suitable norm (e.g., total variation norm) and $C$ is a constant depending on $K$, $\mu$, and $p$?

I am a bit confused, if  $\mu \perp \nu$, then $|\mu-\nu|=|\mu|+|\nu|$, in particular the  denominator of your fraction is not going to zero.
